# How do I scan certain characters from a file

Tags: c, arrays, file, scanf

I am currently working on a sudoku validator, and the way I am doing it is to separate each row into an array of length 9 and check, separate each column into an array of length 9 and check, etc. I have done the rows already doing something like this

```
         for( i=0; i<9; i++)
        fscanf(file, "%1d", &row1[i]);
          for( i=0; i<9; i++)
        fscanf(file, "%1d", &row2[i]);
          for( i=0; i<9; i++)
        fscanf(file, "%1d", &row3[i]);
          for( i=0; i<9; i++)
        fscanf(file, "%1d", &row4[i]);
```

and it works the way I want it too.

I have each number in my sudoku solution separated by a space horizontally and next to each other vertically in my file.

However, I am having trouble trying to scan each column into an array. Basically what I think I need to do is for the first column start at the first (top-left) character and store that into the first slot of my array. Then I need to skip 9 characters and then store that character.

I thought I could do something similar like

```
         for( i=0; i<82; i += 9)
        fscanf(file, "%1d", &col1[i]);
          for( i=1; i<82; i+=9)
        fscanf(file, "%1d", &col2[i]);
          for( i=2; i<82; i+=9)
        fscanf(file, "%1d", &col3[i]);
          for( i=3; i<82; i+=9)
        fscanf(file, "%1d", &col4[i]);
          for( i=4; i<82; i+=9)
```

but I realized it didn't work because I had set my array to size 9 and since i was inserting into the ith value in the array this would not behave like it wanted.

Can anyone give me a suggestion how I could implement this? I think it is fairly trivial but I am having serious trouble wrapping my head around it.

Thanks

Edit: I also need to do this for the region, so i'm basically looking for a way to skip through a file and store only certain characters that I want.

Comment: You must check that you are really scanning the values, in short check the return value of `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a sudoku validator, create a 9 * 9 2D array and read row wise much like you are doing. Then loop through either row wise or column wise to validate your sudoku square.

```
// As pointed out in comments, this code assumes you have a minimum of 9*9 separated ints with width = 1.
// If not, you need to check whether fscanf failed or not.
int sudoku[9][9] ;
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        fscanf(file_ptr, "%1d", &sudoku[i][j]); /* Check for the return value 
                                                 * of fscanf if it is not
                                                 * guaranteed that there 
                                                 * will always be 81 elements 
                                                 * to read from or some other 
                                                 * error occurred while 
                                                 * reading the file.
                                                 */

// now use sudoku to verify.
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
    {
        // sudoku[i][j] is row wise.
        // sudoku[j][i] is column wise.
    }
```

I am assuming you are using C99 or up compiler. If it is C89, you need to move the `int i` and `int j` declarations at the beginning of the function (outside the loop).

Comment: first, your `fscanf()` is wrong, second it will be wrong when you fix it because you don't check for it's return value, which is there for a reason, don't you think?

Comment: Missed the `FILE` pointer. My bad. Also mentioned in the comments how the code is limited.

Comment: you didn't think of a c++ compiler, sometimes they use them without knowing that `c++ != c`.

Comment: A C++ compiler should compile the declarations of variables inside the for loop just fine I suppose?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: hey thanks for the response, but it looks like this is doing both the row and column check at once? My program must be multithreaded, with the row and column checks creating their own threads, which is why I need to scan this way.

Answer (score 0):

Evade all the counting and skipping and read as single characters, with a simple filter. After all, you are only interested in the 81 digits from `1` to `9`, which will *always* appear in the correct order -- no matter what other formatting or neatification is in place. If you also include the `0` or `.` for unknown cells, you can read formats such as this

```
1..|...|7..
.2.|...|5..
6..|38.|...
-----------
.78|...|...
...|6.9|...
...|...|14.
-----------
...|.25|..9
..3|...|.6.
..4|...|..2
```

and also this

```
000605000003020800045090270500000001062000540400000007098060450006040700000203000
```

(examples picked randomly from http://www.sudocue.net/fileformats.php)